# Docker image refuse to run dotnet test command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to embed tests building in docker build process and abort it in case of either of tests fail. My docker file looks like below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
COPY ["WebApplication1.Tests/WebApplication1.Tests.csproj", "WebApplication1.Tests/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS test
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1.Tests
RUN dotnet test --logger:trx

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Does anybody have an idea how to deal with it?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You have a multistage docker file, https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

For your case this will work

```
docker build --target test -t test-tag .
docker build -t webapp-image .
docker run -ti test-tag # will run tests and give you results
```

If you want to see output of other stages you need to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Docker build only generates the docker image from your docker file. It does not run it.

You need to use "docker run" after building your image to actually start the image as a container (which will then perform your entry point command)

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: @Steven_Hardy  I run image and it's successful. But if i delete everything after  RUN dotnet test --logger:trx. Docker throws error saying that tests failed (which is what i expect)